# Data binding for multiple dropdownlists for default shown values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, cascadingdropdown

I have 3 dropdownlists to be populated(cascading). Country, City and Factory. Data does get binded correctly for all three dropdownlists.

The problem is when i select a country, relevant cities get binded correctly to city ddl but for the first value which got selected to city ddl(default shown value), factory ddl doesn't show the relevant factories. But if i choose another element from city ddl and then again if i click on that default shown element of city ddl it works fine. Here is my script

```
<script>
//For ddls
var cityDropdown = $("#SelectedCity"); 

$('#SelectedCountry').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FillCity", "Godown")', 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { Country: $(this).val() }, 
        success: function (cities) {
            cityDropdown.empty();
            $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
                cityDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(city.CityId).html(city.CityName));
            });
        }
    });
})

var factoryDropdown = $("#SelectedFactory"); 
        $('#SelectedCity').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FillFactory", "Godown")', 
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {City: $(this).val() }, 
                success: function (factories) {
                  factoryDropdown.empty();
                    $.each(factories, function (i, factory) {
                       factoryDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(factory.FactoryId).html(factory.FactoryName));
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

All help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean your expecting the factories dropdownlist to be populated when you select a country?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thanks for replying :) No i want factory ddl to be populated when i select a city. It works except the first time when city ddl get populated. I have to choose another element of city ddl and then come to that first element of city ddl to get populated the relevant factories of that first element.

Comment: That what I mean. When you select a Country, the cities are displayed and the first city is selected. Are you expecting the factories for that city to be displayed? (it wont as you currently have it)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, yes you'r correct. im expecting factories for that default selected value of city ddl.

Comment: Then you need to trigger the change event for the cities dropdownlist, but are you sure you want the extra overhead of doing this. Normally you would render a 'Please select' option in cities, so that that is the default, and let the user choose a city which then loads the factories

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, yes i got your point. I am getting 'please select' for all ddls when page loaded. But if i choose a country then in city ddl, some value get selected instead of 'please select'. How to avoid this or trigger the change event of city ddl? shall i update the question to show coding for view for dropdownlists?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, ok thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the `.change()` event of the Cities dropdown list once you populate the cities, so that the associated factories are then loaded

```
$('#SelectedCountry').change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (cities) {
      cityDropdown.empty();
      $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
        cityDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(city.CityId).html(city.CityName));
      });
      $('#SelectedCity').trigger('change'); // add this
    }
  });
})
```

However this is unnecessarily making an ajax call to the server to populate the factories for a city that the user may not be interested in. It would be better to add a default "Please select" option to the cities dropdownlist so that the user can then select a city and populate the associated factories.

```
$('#SelectedCountry').change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (cities) {
      cityDropdown.empty();
      cityDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Please select')); // add this
      $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
        cityDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(city.CityId).html(city.CityName));
      });
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solutions :) Second one works fine and im going to stick with it since it avoids that extra overhead. The first solution when i select a country, gives the city list and show the  first value of that list. But related factories doesn't get populated. Then if i select another city, relevant factories get populated but suddenly that selected city automatically comes to first element and the relevant factory list also get changed based on that city. Pls help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was triggering `.change()` on the wrong element (should be on `SelectedCity`). See update.

Comment: Really thanks for the help. Yes now it is working :)